# calculate difference between two dates and generate new row for each entry

Tags: sql, ssis

I am currently working on SSIS. I have a table with two columns Start and End dates. I need to calculate the days in between (including the start date and end date) and generate a row for each day with the other data repeating. The resulting dates should be stored in a new column.

[image]

Comment: You need to show the desired ouput.

Comment: You indicate the source is a table with the columns as indicated in the above screenshot. Is this SQL Server? If so, what version (2005, 2008, 2012, 2014, 2016) are you using?

Comment: "days in between"?   "resulting dates"?    It's not clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to making this work is to have a table that contains a list of all the days that are in the possible range.

In the following query, I fake it out by using the smallest date in our set `MIN(Start)`.

I then generate a sequence of numbers from 1 to N based on the number of columns in our sys.all_columns views. That might be sufficient, it might not but based on the paucity of data, it works for now. If you need more dates generated, CROSS APPLY the sys.all_coumns table against itself.

I then use the numbers generated to build a list of dates via `dateadd`

I then take my ALLDATES derived table and perform an INNER JOIN to the original table, pinning the date generated for ALLDATES between Start and End columns (end points inclusive).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.so_36392684
(
    WeekNo int NOT NULL
,   Start datetime NOT NULL
,   [End] datetime NOT NULL
,   SpecialEvents varchar(20) NULL
);

INSERT INTO
    dbo.so_36392684
(WeekNo, Start, [End], SpecialEvents)
VALUES
(
    1
,   '1989-09-14'
,   '1989-09-20'
,   NULL
);


SELECT
    S.WeekNo
,   S.Start
,   S.[End]
,   S.SpecialEvents
,   ALLDATES.ConsecutiveDays
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(DAY, D.rn, S.Start) AS ConsecutiveDays
        FROM
            (
                -- Find the first date in our table
                SELECT
                    MIN(S.Start) AS Start
                FROM
                    dbo.so_36392684 AS S
            ) AS S
            CROSS APPLY
            (
                -- Generate a (hopefully) sufficiently large enough set of dates
                SELECT
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS rn
                FROM
                    sys.all_columns AS AC
            ) D
    ) AS ALLDATES
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.so_36392684 AS S
        ON ALLDATES.ConsecutiveDays >= S.Start
        AND ALLDATES.ConsecutiveDays <= S.[End];
```

Result should look something like this

```
WeekNo  Start       End         SpecialEvents   ConsecutiveDays
1       1989-09-14  1989-09-20  NULL            1989-09-14
1       1989-09-14  1989-09-20  NULL            1989-09-15
1       1989-09-14  1989-09-20  NULL            1989-09-16
1       1989-09-14  1989-09-20  NULL            1989-09-17
1       1989-09-14  1989-09-20  NULL            1989-09-18
1       1989-09-14  1989-09-20  NULL            1989-09-19
1       1989-09-14  1989-09-20  NULL            1989-09-20
```